# Simple print in haskell script: how to write main function?

Tags: haskell, printing, program-entry-point

I am starting to learn haskell, but cannot find a way to have a working `main` function. I have already made it work somehow, but I think it was pure luck because I cannot get it again.

Basically, what I want to do is create a script file to be run like `runhaskell script.hs` from terminal.

So the basic structure would be the function declaration followed by a `main = do` or something, and the function being called to print its result.

For example, I took this from "Learn you a Haskell", but the following code doesn't work:

```
elem' :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool  
elem' y ys = foldl (\acc x -> if x == y then True else acc) False ys  

main :: IO()
main = print (elem' 1 [1,2,3,4])
```

This gives me the error:

```
Build FAILED

/home/helton/Desktop/apaga.hs: line 6, column 16:
  Warning: Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type `Integer'
    (Eq a0)
      arising from a use of elem'
      at /home/helton/Desktop/apaga.hs:6:16-20
    (Num a0)
      arising from the literal `1' at /home/helton/Desktop/apaga.hs:6:22
  In the first argument of `print', namely `(elem' 1 [1, 2, 3, 4])'
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (elem' 1 [1, 2, 3, 4])
  In the expression: do { print (elem' 1 [1, 2, 3, 4]) }
    print (elem' 1 [1,2,3,4])
```

While I expected something like

```
> True
```

Comment: Having the build fail completely on a warning of type defaulting (I.e. combining the [`-Werror` and `-fwarn-type-defaults` (the latter implied by `-Wall`) options](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html)) is probably a bit too annoying setting for most users.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I agree. I am just starting to fiddle with haskell using SublimeText for the build cycle. Most probably will tweak the build configuration somehow in the future, and these flags you mentioned look quite useful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
print (elem' 1 [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

with

```
print (elem' (1::Int) [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

The issue here is that Haskell can't determine whether your numeric literals should be interpreted as `Int`s or `Double`s or any other numeric type.

Specifying the type for any numeric literal here is enough, since `elem'` requires all of them to be of the same type, hence once the type of any one of them is known such type can be used for everything else.

Comment: As a relevant comment, I discovered the errors I was getting were actually warnings fired by using `SublimeHaskell`, which apparently tries to "lint" the file on compilation (via some `ghc-mod` stuff).